# Streaming command line input into python2.6

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to stream command line input into python so that I can perform some calculations. The command in question is dstat. Because dstat is a continuous command, I dont think something like commands.getouput('dstat') would work. I am puzzled as to how to get started with this. I would be grateful of any help that is provided.

Comment: Perhaps `subprocess.Popen.communicate` will be useful?

Comment: maybe, how would I use that with dstat?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, gave up on this one. It seemed a bit to complicated to work with open/ended Popen session & dstat. I did find some examples on the Net for this, but way to complicated than I had time for. At some point I will come back to this. As I believe working with open/ended Popen sessions may prove useful.

I ended up looping through mpstat. The overall purpose was to get a different perspective of CPU spikes we were seeing.I ended up doing the following.

```
#! /usr/bin/python


import os
import commands
import subprocess
import sys

threshold = float(sys.argv[1])
print threshold
print type(threshold)

temp_page = open('/tmp/cpustats.txt', 'ab')

while True:
        cpst = commands.getoutput('mpstat | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f1,7,15')
        cpustat = cpst.split()
        if ( (float(cpustat[1])+float(cpustat[2]))>= threshold):
                date = commands.getoutput("date +\%b\" \"\%d\" \"%g\" \"\%I:%M:%S")
                #print cpustat[1], cpustat[2]
                cputotal = float(cpustat[1])+float(cpustat[2])
                temp_page.write("CPU SPIKE ON "+date+" CPU LOAD "+str(cputotal)+"\n")
```